# Highcharts oncahnge event It works on the first try but not on the second try

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I'm coding a graph that expresses the day-by-day graph.

I want to change the graph through select tag.

So, i use javascript onchange.

But, It works on the first try but not on the second try.

https://jsfiddle.net/7eqn02yu/

This is my code JS fiddle.
And this is code.
How does the function run every time?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>

<button id="export-pdf">Export PDF</button>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="./index.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<select id="mySelect">
<option value="0">mon</option>
<option value="1">tues</option>
<option value="2">wed</option>
<option value="3">thr</option>
</select>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; width: 500px"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            point: {
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
document.getElementById("mySelect").onchange = function () { myFunction() };
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    if (x = 0) {
        const series = chart.series[0];
        if (series.data.length) {
            chart.series[0].remove();
        }
        chart.addSeries({
            data: [100, 100, 100, 100, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5]
        });
    } else if (x = 1) {
        const series = chart.series[0];
        if (series.data.length) {
            chart.series[0].remove();
        }
        chart.addSeries({
            data: [200, 200, 200, 200, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5]
        });
    } else if (x = 2) {
        const series = chart.series[0];
        if (series.data.length) {
            chart.series[0].remove();
        }
        chart.addSeries({
            data: [200, 200, 200, 200]
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` were wrong formatted :

```
if (x = 0){
```

should be

```
if (x == 0){
```

Now it works [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/1svjLq0f/)

Comment: Oh...I'm very ashamed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `if (x=0) use if (x===0)` and for the rest of the else if's

as following:

```
if (x = 0){   // Use if (x === 0){ 
   ...
else if (x = 1){  // use else if (x===1)
    const series = chart.series[0];
   ...
  }else if (x = 2){// use else if (x===2)
```